# VF Email Template and Custom Controller ... Issue with Lightning Email Quick Action

Tags: email, quickaction

I have an Email Quick Action on Lead and using a VF page Email Template.
The VF Email template refers Components and Apex Code and depends on RelatedTo.Id being passed. 
I am not able to fetch the Custom Controller data into the Email Template when the template is selected in the Lightning Email action.
When i do a 'Send Test' Preview, it is coming up well. 
Please give some pointers.

Any pointers much appreciated. Searching on discussion forums didn't throw any light.

Thanks,
CK

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the answer to this. posting here for future reference in this forum.
In my VF Email template, i was passing the RelatedTo.Id to the component. For this situation, the value is always null. So instead , i passed recipient.id and it worked..

Thanks,
CK